# Gtk.Vte and feed_child: command sent two time

Tags: python, gtk3

i'm building a tabbed python terminal to manage multiple ssh connection (like superputty or putty manager on windows), so i use feed_child to send command to terminal, but there is a little problem: the command is written 2 time in the terminal, on time before everything.. code is better:

I use this to send the command (in this case for example the command is `uptime`)

```
if self.command != "":
        self.length_command = len(self.command) + 1
        self.hbox.term.feed_child(self.command + "\n", self.length_command)
```

but in the terminal i get this result

```
uptime
maurelio@myhost1 ~ $ uptime
19:04:18 up 15 days, 14:32,  2 users,  load average: 0,04, 0,07, 0,14
maurelio@myhost1
```

As you can see, `uptime` appears in terminal like normal text when i start the program or open a new tab, then appear the prompt and the command is correctly executed. i'd like to get just this:

```
maurelio@myhost1 ~ $ uptime
19:04:18 up 15 days, 14:32,  2 users,  load average: 0,04, 0,07, 0,14
maurelio@myhost1
```

Any idea?

**Update**
Here there is a complete code (that should works) :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
from gi.repository import Gtk, Vte, GLib
import os

class Terminal(Vte.Terminal):
    """Just create a standard terminal with some configuration
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(Terminal, self).__init__()
        self.configure_terminal()

    def configure_terminal(self):
        self.set_audible_bell(False)
        self.set_visible_bell(False)
        self.set_sensitive(True)
        self.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/bash"], 
                    [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)

class Window(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Terminal")

        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.term = Terminal()
        self.box.pack_start(self.term, True, True, 0)

        self.term.set_audible_bell(False)
        self.term.set_visible_bell(False)
        self.term.set_sensitive(True)
        self.term.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, os.environ['HOME'], ["/bin/bash"], 
                    [], GLib.SpawnFlags.DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD, None, None)

        self.command = 'uptime'
        self.length_command = len(self.command) + 1
        self.term.feed_child(self.command + "\n", self.length_command)

        self.term.connect("child-exited", Gtk.main_quit)


win = Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

If you run this, you will see the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the Vte terminal to a ScrolledWindow first:

```
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Terminal")
    self.set_default_size(600, 300)

    self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
    self.add(self.box)

    self.term = Terminal()
    self.sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.sw.add(self.term)
    self.box.pack_start(self.sw, True, True, 0)
```